JavaScript is multiplying by 2 instead of adding by 1
I have a piece of code that has a text with an id, a button with a function to go to JavaScript to add a number every 10 seconds my problem is instead of adding 1 number it multiplies by 2
This is what I tried


function autoclick() {
  var x = Math.floor((Math.random() + 1) + 0, ),
    el = document.getElementById('test'),
    val = parseInt(el.innerHTML, 10);
  el.innerHTML = val + x;
  var t = setInterval(autoclick, 1000);
}
<p id="test">0</p>
<button onclick="autoclick()">autoclick</button>




Every time autoclick executes, you are creating an additional timer interval - so you have multiple intervals running in parallel, all executing autoclick. If you want to set up the next function call from within the function - then you should be using setTimeout, to trigger one next call.

(And that your x will always have the value 1, is clear to you?)

why + 0 in Math.floor? Why the second empty argument to Math.floor?

@JaromandaX I'm actually surprised this works. Used to be a syntax error. I guess they finally ratified the change that fn(a, b, ) is acceptable.

@VLAZ I'm not surprised it works, I'm wondering why OP is even bothering with that ,

You need to call the setting of the interval only once and update the value value in another function.


let t;

function start() {
   t = setInterval(update, 1000);
   document.getElementById('start').disabled = true;
   document.getElementById('stop').disabled = false;
}

function stop() {
   clearInterval(t);
   document.getElementById('start').disabled = false;
   document.getElementById('stop').disabled = true;
}

function update() {
    const test = document.getElementById('test');
    test.innerHTML = +test.innerHTML + 1;
}
<p id="test">0</p>
<button id="start" onclick="start()">autoclick</button>
<button id="stop" onclick="stop()" disabled="disabled">stop</button>




of course, stop is useless if you click autoclick more than once :p
